# Вывод дерева mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, дерево

Есть таблица elements следующей структуры Adjacency List Model:

```
id parent index
```

Где index - это порядок элемента.
Нужно одним запросом сформировать путь, получающийся при обходе в глубину.
То есть если у нас такой вид:

```
1 0 1
2 0 2
3 1 1
4 1 2
5 2 1
6 0 3
```

То выведется
1 3 4 2 5 6

Нужно на чистом mysql без использования php и тд.
Заранее спасибо

P.S. Менять в структуре, к сожалению, ничего нельзя

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Создай функцию вместо использования запроса

Comment: Дерево у вас и так в таблице должно содержаться. Выводить можно узлы дерева.

Comment: В PostgreSQL поддерживаются рекурсивные запросы WITH RECURSIVE, а в Oracle иерархические запросы (hierarchical query clause (also known as “CONNECT BY query”) or recursive subquery factoring).

Comment: MySQL не поддерживает рекурсивных запросов. А потому вариантов два. Первый - создание хранимой процедуры, которая отдаст требуемые данные. Второй - создание дополнительной таблицы, в которой будут храниться преобразованные из исходного вида данные в удобном для решения поставленной задачи формате плюс код (триггер и/или эвент), актуализирующий эту таблицу при внесении изменений в исходную.

Comment: Спасибо за ваши комментарии. Я все понял

Answer (score 5):

В MySQL нет штатных средств для работы с рекурсивными запросами. Но как известно, если очень хочется, то можно (хотя выглядит это жутковато и оптимизации по скорости это не поддается):

```
select id,path
  from (
   select  @path:=if(@id!=id,`index`,
             coalesce(
               (select concat(`index`,'/',@path)
                  from Tree1 where id=@pid)
             ,@path)
           ) path,
           @pid:=if(@id!=id,parent,
             (select parent from Tree1 N
               where id=@pid)
             ),
            @id:=id id, N
     from Tree1 T,
          (select @n:=@n+1 N
             from Tree1,(select @n:=0) N limit 3) Seq,
          (select @id:=0,@path:='') X
    order by id, N
  ) X
 where N=3
 order by path
```

Так как ни рекурсии ни циклов в обычном смысле слов нет, то запрос эмулирует рекурсию с помощью эмуляции цикла. В качестве цикла используется склейка с любой таблицей, в которой записей не менее, чем максимально возможный уровень иерархии в дереве. В данном примере используется выборка из той же самой таблицы, явно ограниченная `limit 3` (если вложенность дерева больше - число надо соответственно увеличить). Собственно данные из этой таблицы не берутся, а создаются порядковые номера (`N`).

После этой склейки у нас в выборке появляется по 3 записи с одним и тем же id. На каждой из них, с помощью переменных, мы получаем id очередной родительской ветки, углубляясь по дереву (так как переменные помнят значения, сформированные в предыдущей строке). Самое главное, что мы тут формируем это путь к данной записи в виде индексов сортировки (если index может быть более 9 то для правильной сортировки надо выравнивать его в пути до одинаковой длины с помощью `lpad()`)

В какой то момент записи родителей заканчиваются, мы дошли до корня дерева, тогда подзапрос индекса родителя возвращает NULL и при этом с помощью coalesce мы сохраняем ранее сформированный путь. Таким образом в последней записи нашего "цикла" у нас гарантированно будет полный путь до данного листа дерева. Нам остается только убрать из выборки рабочие строки цикла с частично сформированными путями, т.е. выбрать только последние строки (`where N=3`) и отсортировать по пути индексов.

Comment: Настоящий профессионал

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы вывести полный путь в одном запросе нужно использовать [Nested Set Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). (Полная информация по [ссылке](https://web.archive.org/web/20110606032941/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html))

> Для построения пути можно использовать хранимую функцию. При
>   процедурном языке мы можем начать в нижней части дерева и перебирать
>   вверх, чтобы вернуть полное дерево или единственный путь.

https://web.archive.org/web/20110606032941/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/169152)

Comment: @cheops Что нужно указать?