# Mysql учитывать дочек

Tags: php, mysql

добавить например условие, если например чтобы искал еще и в подкатегориях выбранной категории? то есть например есть такая структуру

```
65 
-67 
--68
```

если мы указываем категорию 65, то и искал в нижних категориях?

```
modx_ms2_orders - таблица заказов
modx_ms2_order_products - товары из таблицы заказов
modx_site_content - список ресурсов, здесь идет ограничение по родителю
```

на данный момент он ищет сумму по всем заказам, без учета mc.parent

```
SELECT SUM(mp.cost) as cost, MONTH(mo.createdon) as m FROM `modx_ms2_orders` mo 
inner join `modx_ms2_order_products` mp on mp.order_id = mo.id 
inner JOIN `modx_site_content` mc on mc.id=mp.product_id and mc.parent=81 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(mo.`createdon`, '%Y') = 2019 GROUP by MONTH(mo.createdon)
```

Comment: Укажите точную версию сервера.

Comment: Если у вас mysql версии меньше 8.0 то вам очень не повезло и это можно сделать только с жуткими извращениями, как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/673240/194569 Если версия 8, то вам повезло, вы можете использовать рекурсивный CTE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-examples

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.35, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: а как  под это сделать  ru.stackoverflow.com/a/673240/194569?